# Apache Airflow: Conditionals running before triggered

Tags: airflow

I'm having a problem with my DAG. I want to set it up to where if one task fails, another happens and the entire run doesn't fail.

The code is proprietary so I can't post the code snippet. So sorry!

Task0 >> [Task1, Task2]
Task1 >> Task1a

If Task1 fails, I want task2 to execute. If task1 is successful, I want task1a to execute. My current code for task2 looks like this:

```
task2 = DummyOperator(
   task_id='task2',
   trigger_rule='one_failed',
   dag=dag,
)
```

I've been playing around with the trigger_rule but this keeps running before task1. It just runs right away.

Comment: If solved your issue consider upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator is fine. The dependency is wrong.

The `Task0 >> [Task1, Task2] >> Task1a` means that Task1 can run in parallel with Task2 and the trigger_rule='one_failed' of Task2 is checked against it's direct upstream tasks. This means that the rule is checked against `Task0` status not against `Task1`.

To fix your issue you need to change:

```
Task0 >> Task1 >> Task2 
Task1 >> Task1a
```